# Using .Where clause and conditional to Filter Array

Tags: c#, filter, where-clause

I have 2 `IEnumerable` lists that have a method called `GetId()` which returns an `integer`.

```
IEnumerable oldBoats
IEnumerable updatedBoats
```

I want to compare both lists. If `updatedBoats.getId()` returns a unique Id compared to `oldBoats`, I want to add it to a list.

So I did this:

```
IEnumerable<Boat> newBoats = updatedBoats
    .Where(c => oldBoats
    .Any(d => d.GetId() != c.GetId())
    .ToList()
```

The current IDs for `oldBoats` and `newBoats` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I want to test the base case and this does not pass. The `newBoats` always returns a list for all the IDs when it should return `none`. Am I doing the ordering of `c` and `d` wrong?

Comment: `Where` does not return a `bool`. Your internal `Where` would probably be an `Any`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks I updated the question but I'm still returning all integers

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, you say `If newBoats.getId() returns a unique Id`, can you explain that properly?

Comment: I would try with a Select to get the ids from oldBoats and then a where on the updatedBoats to check what is not in the ids

Comment: Please provide us with the code for `GetId()`, and what is in `updatedBoats` when you run that code.

Comment: So `newBoats` should contain `oldBoats` including any new ones in `updatedBoats`?

Comment: @DavidG For now I just want newBoats to contain any new objects from the updatedBoats list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
var newBoats = updatedBoats.Where(u => !oldBoats.Any(o => o.GetId() == u.GetId()));
```

Answer (score 4):

What this code does

```
IEnumerable<Boat> newBoats = updatedBoats.Where(c=> oldBoats.Any(d =>d.GetId() != c.GetId()).ToList()
```

roughly translates to: "give me all of the updated boats whose ID doesn't match at least one of the old boat IDs". That isn't what you want. The logic you want is "give me all of the updated boats whose ID doesn't match any of the old boat IDs", and that is correctly specified by @zeroef:

```
var newBoats = updatedBoats.Where(u => !oldBoats.Any(o => o.GetId() == u.GetId()));  
// This is O(o * n) for # of old boats * # of updates that are new boats, and something like O((o/2)*n) for # of old boats * number of updated old boats
```

That said, note my comment. This would be more efficiently implemented using a `HashSet<T>`:

```
// This is O(n) for # of updated boats
var newBoatIds = new HashSet<Int32>(updatedBoats.Select(b => b.GetId())); 
// This is O(n) for # of old boats
newBoatIds.ExceptWith(oldBoats.Select(b => b.GetId()));
```

This reduces the number of nested iterations significantly, and you'll see a difference if you have a lot of boats (and particularly if you have a lot of new boats in your update).

The HashSet approach works for IDs, but you can also make it work for entities themselves if you implement Equals() and GetHashcode() on the Boat class using the ID for comparison.